# MariaDB ROW_NUMBER with ORDER BY not ordering correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-order-by

I've set-up a simple query to get my menu items ordered by the corresponding language message content, but weirdly enough this doesn't set the row numbers correctly. Here's the query:

```
SET @idx = 0;
SELECT (@idx:=@idx + 1) AS neworderindex, a.id, a.messagecontent FROM (
    SELECT m.id, l.messagecontent
    FROM app_menuitem m 
    INNER JOIN app_language l ON m.id = l.messagekey AND l.locale = 'it'
    WHERE m.parent_id = 'some.parent.id'
    ORDER BY l.messagecontent
) a;
```

I tried executing the subquery first and the results are ordered correctly, I just don't know what's going on with the @idx variable.

Comment: You must specify the ordering on the level where your calculatoins are performed - i.e. in outer query, not in subquery.

Comment: @Akina I already tried, but the neworderindex still isn't correct.

Comment: Provide a fiddle with some sample data and desired result for it.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you running?

Comment: @GMB 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.messagecontent) as neworderindex,
       m.id, l.messagecontent
FROM app_menuitem m INNER JOIN
     app_language l
     ON m.id = l.messagekey AND l.locale = 'it'
WHERE m.parent_id = 'some.parent.id'
ORDER BY l.messagecontent;
```

This functionality was released in 2016 with MariaDB 10.2.0.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! I might've missed the update :)